# Is there a way to add objects to a vector by reference without using pointers?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have 2 vectors and 1 object. I add the object to both vectors, then I alter the object. I want the change to appear in both vectors:

This doesn't work (outputs `1`):

```
class Entity {
    public:
    int x;
    Entity() {}
    Entity(int y) : x(y) {}
};

int main()
{
  Entity e = Entity(1);
  vector<Entity> vec1;
  vector<Entity> vec2;
  vec1.push_back(e);
  vec2.push_back(e);
  vec1[0].x = 5;
    
  cout << vec2[0].x << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This does work, but wondering if there's a way to use & reference:

```
class Entity {
    public:
    int x;
    Entity() {}
    Entity(int y) : x(y) {}
};

int main()
{
  Entity* e = new Entity(1);
  vector<Entity*> vec1;
  vector<Entity*> vec2;
  vec1.push_back(e);
  vec2.push_back(e);
  vec1[0]->x = 5;
    
  cout << vec2[0]->x << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not with raw reference. References don't really exist. They are intended to be an additional name for something that already exists, so they don't necessarily have anything that you can put in a `vector`. [Quoting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference): *References are not objects; they do not necessarily occupy storage[,]* and *Because references are not objects, there are no arrays of references, no pointers to references, and no references to references:*

Comment: In the pointer case, you may habvve an excellent opportunity to practice working with [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Answer (score 2):

Make it a `vector` of [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) and it should work:

```
int main()
{
  Entity e = Entity(1);
  vector<std::reference_wrapper<Entity>> vec1;
  vector<std::reference_wrapper<Entity>> vec2;
  vec1.push_back(e);
  vec2.push_back(e);
  vec1[0].x = 5;
    
  cout << vec2[0].x << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

`reference_wrapper` is constructable from the types it wraps, so you don't need to explicitly use `std::ref`/`std::cref` to make it.

Comment: This _technically_ works for the OP's provided code sample, but it doesn't really scale if you have multiple instances of `Entity`, since _something_ needs to own the original `Entity` object(s).

Comment: What would be the best way then? Pointers? unique_ptr?

Comment: @doctopus `std::shared_ptr` would make more sense, since you are *sharing* ownership between the original creator and the 2 vectors, so the `Entity` won't be destroyed until all 3 are done using it.

Comment: @KarlNicoll: Agreed. It's a useful solution for cases where the ownership of the actual objects is clear and they're guaranteed to continue existing beyond the lifetime of the `vector` of `reference_wrapper`, but in many cases `std::shared_ptr` (constructed with `std::make_shared` for efficiency) is a better solution since you don't need bounded lifetimes like you do with `vector<reference_wrapper<T>>` (where the lifetime of that `vector` must be a subset of the lifetime of the real owner).

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to determine exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I think you'll need pointers to achieve it. You **can** improve your ownership though to make it a bit more pallatable.

For example, `vec1` can store a list of `unique_ptr` instances, which ensures that `vec1` *owns those objects*, and `vec2` can store non-owning raw pointers which don't need to trigger a `delete`. For example:

```
#include <memory>

class Entity {
    public:
    int x;
    Entity() {}
    Entity(int y) : x(y) {}
};

int main()
{
  auto e = make_unique<Entity>(1);
  vector<unique_ptr<Entity>> vec1;    // vec1 owns the objects...  
  vector<Entity*> vec2;               // ... while vec2 holds just pointers

  // Add the owning unique_ptr to vec1. Moving is required for a unique_ptr,
  // Since we have to transfer ownership to the vector.
  vec1.push_back(move(e));

  // Store a non-owning pointer in vec2.
  vec2.push_back(vec1.back().get());
  vec1[0]->x = 5;
    
  cout << vec2[0]->x << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::shared_ptr` to keep a pointer in both vectors, and ensure that the pointer lives as long as both vectors do, and cleans up once both `vec1` and `vec2` are destroyed:

```
#include <memory>

class Entity {
    public:
    int x;
    Entity() {}
    Entity(int y) : x(y) {}
};

int main()
{
  auto e = make_shared<Entity>(1);
  vector<shared_ptr<Entity>> vec1;      // Both vec1 and vec2 share ownership of the pointer.
  vector<shared_ptr<Entity>> vec2;

  vec1.push_back(e);
  vec2.push_back(move(e));
  vec1[0]->x = 5;

  cout << vec2[0]->x << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Sidenote: In this second example, I `move()`d `e`. This provides a very small optimization for `shared_ptr`, since we don't need our instance of `e` anymore once `vec1` and `vec2` both have copies.

Comment: _Alternatively, you could use `std::shared_ptr`_ That makes more sense to me.  The vectors share ownership of the underlying objects, no?

Comment: Neat trick, but I'd drop a comment explaining why you `move` in `vec2.push_back(move(e));` Took me a few seconds to figure out the goal.

Comment: Yes, but obviously it depends on what the OP is trying to do. If the vectors genuinely share ownership, then `shared_ptr` is the way to go. But if their intention was to have a single source of `Entity` objects, and hold references to those objects everywhere else in the code (like a Flyweight pattern), then there's a clear ownership pattern and I'd personally prefer to use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @user4581301 Done! Also fixed a sneaky mistake when doing `vec2.push_back(e.get())` :-P